# How to read an unknown type file of unknown size

Tags: delphi, tfilestream

I need to read the content of an unknown type and size file and temporary save it (in some kind of variable) so I use it later for transferring through serial port. As far as I understand, TFileStream is the right approach.

I did try implementing the following tutorial from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/TReader_(Delphi)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Utils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure OnCreate(Sender: TObject);

    private
      selectedFile: string;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
  function ReadFileContent(fileName: String): String;
  var
    FileStream: TFileStream;
    Reader: TReader;
    tByte :byte;

  begin

    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead);
    Reader := TReader.Create(FileStream, $FF);

    Reader.ReadListBegin;           //I get 'Invalid property Value' error
                                    //in this line raised from the Reader object

    while not Reader.EndOfList do
    begin
      Reader.ReadVar(tByte, 1);
    end;

    Reader.ReadListEnd;

    Reader.Destroy;
    FileStream.Destroy;
  end;

var
  dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
  selectedFile := '';
  dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.InitialDir := '.\';
    dlg.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';
    if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
      selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
end;

if selectedFile <> '' then
  ReadFileContent(selectedFile);
end;
end.
```

Is there anything else I need to set for the Reader object to work properly or I should use a different approach?

Comment: TReader is the wrong component here, as it is meant for reading streamed components. As mentioned elsewhere, `TFile.ReadAllText` from _System.IOUtils_ is the easiest way to read a text file into a string.

Comment: @UweRaabe Im sorry, I have edited my question. I am not trying to read text.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "save it"? If you want to copy a file, you can use a copy file function. Or do you want to obtain a byte array of the file? If so, use `ReadAllBytes` instead of `ReadAllText`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thank you. I am editing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to read the content of an unknown type and size file and save
>   it into a string.

Since you want to save it in a string, either

1. the file is a text file, or
2. you are doing it wrong (a string can only store textual data).

Assuming the first option, you can simply do

```
MyStringVariable := TFile.ReadAllText('C:\myfile.txt');
```

(`uses IOUtils`).

There is also an overload of `ReadAllText` that you can use to specify the encoding (e.g., UTF-8 or UTF-16LE).

**Update.** The question was edited and now reads

> I need to read the content of an unknown type and size file and save it.

Do you simply want to copy a file? If so, you can use any of the file-copying methods that are available, such as the [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) Win32 function, `TFile.Copy` from IOUtils, and many more.

Or do you want to obtain the bytes of the file so you can process it in your application? If so, my original answer is close to what you need. Just use `ReadAllBytes` instead of `ReadAllText`:

```
MyDynamicByteArray := TFile.ReadAllBytes('C:\logo.bmp');
```

where `MyDynamicByteArray` is a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) of bytes (`TArray<Byte>`, that is, `array of byte`).

Comment: In that case, I am editing my question in order to get an answer for option 2.
Thank you

Comment: TFile.ReadAllBytes stored in a dynamic array is what I am looking for. Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: @Mikemik: Thank you.